# how to register collection of generic interfaces in autofac

Tags: generics, collections, ienumerable, autofac, resolve

Does anyone know how to get this property populated by autofac:

```
public IEnumerable<ITransactionProcessor<TransactionBase>> TransactionHandlers { get; set; }
```

with these two concrete implementations:

```
public class FeeTransactionProcessor : ITransactionProcessor<FeeTransaction> 
public class InterestTransactionProcessor : ITransactionProcessor<InterestTransaction>
```

Strangely, the code below works fine and I get 2 items in the collection, which both implement ITestTransactionProcessor:

```
public IEnumerable<ITestTransactionProcessor> TestTransactionHandlers { get; set; }
```

Notice:

```
IEnumerable<ITransactionProcessor<TransactionBase>>
```

versus:

```
IEnumerable<ITestTransactionProcessor>
```

The autofac version is 2.4.4 (if it makes any difference).

I can supply more code/details, but I thought this would give a good idea of what I am trying to achieve.

The background is that we load a list of transactions for a customer and we need to calculate the balance of the customers account. We would like to have a set of processors (one per each transaction type), that take transaction and a summary object as input and spit out an updated version of the summary object, which gets passed around through all processors that are needed to calculate balance for one customer. So we load customer, his transactions and loop through each transaction and call the factory object to get a processor for given transaction and once we have processor we go:

```
state = processor.Process(transaction, state);
```

until we processed all transactions. Then we should have the balance. Unfortunately autofac doesnt load the processors and so the factory returns null for every transaction type :/

Thanks in advance,
Lukasz

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure `ITransactionProcessor<T>` has `T` marked as contravariant, i.e.:

```
interface ITransactionProcessor<in T> { ... }
```

Then, enable contravariant resolve in Autofac:

```
builder.RegisterSource(new ContravariantRegistrationSource());
```